# Duplicated icons with toastr

Tags: toastr

I have several icons on top of each other in a toastr message. This is what it looks like:

[image]

My code is very simple, I use toastr after an Ajax call :

```
 success        : function(reponse) {
            $(event.target).next('i').hide();
            if (reponse.retour == 0){
                toastr["success"](reponse.texte_retour);
                } else {
                toastr["error"](reponse.texte_retour);
                }
        }
```

I have the same problem whatever the type (error, info, warning, success). What is going wrong?

Comment: The problem is that there are multiple icons overlapping each other?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Don't understand why.

Comment: the problem is solved. I use "inspinia template" and the css was already declared in this template. So it was not necessary to duplicate the css style in the html file. Now it works fine. Sorry and thank you for your question. Merci. Dominique

Comment: No problem! This could be something that happens to someone else in the future, so the question may be worth keeping around. You could post an answer yourself once you can. I'll edit the title to make the problem a bit clearer.

Comment: @Pekka웃 this question helped me. If it didn't exist, I'd probably lost a couple of hours until figuring this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Another way to resolve this issue is to load the toastr css before you load the inspinia css. This way Inspinia overwrites the toastr css with its own custom css

Comment: This solution worked for me and allowed to keep other config options.

Answer (score 13):

The issue is solved.

I use '[inspinia](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S) framework'. in its style sheet there is already somme css declaration about toastr :

[image]

I commented these few lines and now it works fine. Don't know if it is a bug or not on the "inspinia" side.

Dominique

Comment: This solution will be lost after Inspinia update. @Reyske solution work for me and will not overwrite default Inspinia style.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue, I checked my reference links to my css, I found that I was calling "toastrStyles" css after "inspania" css. I moved calling my "toastrStyles" css before calling "inspania" css, and it worked for me.

Comment: You are welcome. And you can delete the no longer required comments, too ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using font-awesome icons along with the default icons.

Adding this to your css should fix the overlapping icons by hiding the default image.

```
#toast-container > div.toast {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Also if you want to vertical center your image add

```
#toast-container > .toast:before {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto 1.5em auto -1.5em;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to be done with any of the css customisations.Just keep your
toastr css immediately after boostrap(if using)  and before any other css links.Its will work without any issues.

likes this:

```
 <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="~/Content/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

....remaining links here after.....comes

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue with Inspinia. The reason was I loaded the toastr css file after the inspinia css file (style.css) causing the toastr css to overwrite the inspinia styles.

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing css import order was not helpful at all. In that happens to you as well, you could override classes:

```
#toast-container > .toast-error:before {
  content: none;
}

#toast-container > .toast-success:before {
  content: none;
}
```

It is similar to @Dom answer, but without changing inspinia or toastr code itself.

Answer (score 0):

loading toastr css before any other css, fix this problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

use ng7-snack-bar
https://angular-4hvr9p.stackblitz.io
4 different states, rank and avoid duplicates.
Auto close on transition. 
AOT